# Express body-parser supports both Content-Type 'text/plain' and 'application/json'

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

```
router.post('/action', bodyParser.text(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    // ...
    res.send('ok');
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('not ok');
  }
});
```

I could have the above code for `Content-Type: 'text/plain'` and I could have the below code for `Content-Type: 'application/json'`, but now I need to support them both, how? Is there an option in bodyParser that supports both 'text/plain' and 'application/json'?

```
router.post('/action', bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    body = req.body;
    // ...
    res.send('ok');
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('not ok');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Never mind I figured this out:

```
router.post('/action', bodyParser.text({
  type: ['json', 'text']
}), async function(req, res) {
  try {
    body = typeof req.body === 'string' ? JSON.parse(req.body) : req.body;
    // ...
    res.send('ok');
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('not ok');
  }
});
```